# Getting connection Open when Using a SqlConnection block within Another Block

Tags: c#, sql-server, using

In the project I call a method to query additional information with a *SqlConnection block*, but then I validate if exists in a second table using another *sqlconnection block*, but it is supposed to be disposed (closed) after getting back to the method **InsertNewData**, but when calling to Open the connection for the Insert, I'm getting the following message:

> The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.

My code is like this:

```cs
public void InsertNewData(string operation)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        if (operation!= string.Empty)
        {
            using (SqlConnection oconn = new SqlConnection(myDBone))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                string query = "SELECT * FROM operations "+
                "WHERE idoper=@id";
                oconn.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand(query, oconn);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", operation.ToString()));
                da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);
            }
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(myDBtwo))
                {
                    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
                    string query= "";
                    foreach (DataRow x in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        if (ValidateData(x) == false)
                        {
                            query= "INSERT INTO history(iddata,description, datehist ) "+
                            " VALUES(@id,@descrip,GETDATE())";
                            con.Open();  //Here throws the Exception error
                            com = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                            com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", x["idoper"].ToString()));
                            com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@descrip", x["description"] ));
                            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception x)
    {
        throw x;
    }
}

public bool ValidateData(DataRow row)
{
    bool exists= false;

    string operation= row["idoper"].ToString();
    string descrip= row["description"].ToString();
    if (operation!= string.Empty && descrip!= string.Empty)
    {
        using (SqlConnection oconn = new SqlConnection(sqlrastreo))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            string query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM history "+
            "WHERE iddata=@id AND description=@descrip";
            oconn.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand(query, oconn);
            com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", operation));
            com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@descrip", descrip));
            int count = (int) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            if (count > 0)
                exists= true;
        }// Here it should be Disposed or closed the SqlConnection
    }
    return exists;
}
```

What I'm doing wrong, because it's suppose to be closed the other connection and the other hasn't been opened ? or Should I Still call the Close() method for each SqlConnection inside the block *Using*?

**Updated:**
I've changed to parameters for best reading code and recommendation syntax.

**NOTE**
The values and parameters aren't the real ones, my real table *descriptions* have about 8 fields, but I validate with just two parameters that aren't primary key, but considering that I can't edit the table properties (Have only reading permissions for that database).

**Update 2:** 
Thanks to the recommendation of *[Sean Lange](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3813116/sean-lange)*, it was better and so simple to use a Store Procedure (SP) to validate and insert at the same time, so I do it as follow in code of the process:

```cs
public void InsertNewData(string operation)
{
    try
    {
        if(operation == string.Empty)
            return;
        using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(myDBtwo))
        {
            con.Open();
            var cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_InsertData", con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", operation));
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
     }
     catch(Exception  ex)
     { throw ex; }
}
```

And then in my SP I insert a select statement of the parameter, to avoid duplicates and also do it in One go:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_InsertData @id VARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO History
    SELECT O.idoper, O.description
    FROM myDBone.dbo.operations O
    LEFT JOIN History H 
    ON H.iddata = O.idoper AND H.description = O.description
    WHERE O.idoper=@id AND H.iddata IS NULL
END
```

Thanks for your support, and hope it helps someone.

Comment: You desperately need to read about, understand and start using parameters in your queries. This is wide open to sql injection. My friend bobby tables loves this style of coding. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: For the problem at hand where is this error being thrown? And what is the point of a try/catch if all the catch does is catch the error and throw it again? All that is accomplishing is to slow your application down. Either properly handle the error or just let it happen.

Comment: Oh I see the error...in the method InsertData you have a loop and you open the connection each iteration through the loop. Move that open before the loop. And then go fix your queries to use parameters.

Comment: Dangit @sean lange, while I was typing...At any rate, Albert, you don't need that validate method, you're simply doing more work than needs to be done.  If you try to Insert and the row already exists, SQL will tell you, you just have to catch that error response and act on it.

Comment: Even better than trying to insert a duplicate would be to use a NOT EXISTS in your insert so it won't insert the duplicate at all.

Comment: I know about Sql Injection, but since it's a local process (exe), I considered that wasn't neccesary. But I'll take your recommendation, to update it :)

Comment: It is always necessary. It is so simple to parameterize that not doing it is borderline negligent. Personally I would consider reworking this whole thing to use a table value parameter to a stored procedure. That way you can pass in the entire collection of data at once and use a single insert statement to insert all of the non-existent data in one step. Way simpler code and faster performance. Everybody wins!!

Comment: Oh you really true _Sean Lange_ , I'll change the iteration and validation out of the SqlConnection block, and check if the exeption isn't throw again, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First your code is badly written,as they have suggested you don't need to validate,try catch will do it for you.second opening a connection inside a loop ( foreach in your case) will will result to trying to open already open connection. Example here you could do something like

```cs
  query= "INSERT INTO history(iddata,description, datehist" VALUES(@id,@descrip,GETDATE())";
   using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(myDBtwo))
            {
           con.Open();
   SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query,con);
                foreach (DataRow x in dt.Rows)
                {     
                        com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", x["idoper"].ToString()));
                        com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@descrip", x["description"] ));
                        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: the try catch has only the purpose to alert, in another method via email, when a error is handled to keep testing the process, and also know if there were a connection error to the database, that's the reason I'm using  :)